# What programming language to use for sending mail from web?

Tags: email, mailing-list

I created advance mail sender desktop application but have some problem with it. There are some limitation, so for solving those limitation I have to send mail from web, but I didn't use much web programming before, so now my question is **what is best web programming language for sending mail from web?**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I definitely recommend PHP for this task, have a look at http://swiftmailer.org/ also ..

Answer (score 5):

There is no best programming language for such trivial task. The choice should depend on your knowledge of the field and your server compatibility.

PHP is probably the most widely supported web programming language. Almost every unix and windows hosting account, from the cheaper to the most expensive, supports it.

Other alternatives are Python and Ruby.

If you use a Windows server, the alternative is classic ASP or ASP.net.